# How to query 'range' or 'between' in redis hashOperations?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm setting up spring data redis in my project. I use RedisTemplate for query. I want to make couple of methods like save/get. It's first time I use Redis. I have a butch entities which I should save.

So my save method is something like this

```
public void save(List<Entity> entities){
   entities.forEach(e -> {
       redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(KEY, e.getId(), e);
       }
   };
}
```

My entity looks like

```
class Entity {
  private String id;
  private long millis;
  etc...
}
```

So the question!!! How to make get query and find all entities which are between 'millis'

I have a get method

```
public List<Entity> fetchAll(Long start, Long end){
   HOW TO MAKE QUERY???
}
```

**I don't need ZSet because in my case it's possible to have duplicates**

Comment: Do you mean that you expect duplicate IDs or millis?

Comment: @TheDude It's my first time I work with Redis and I was wrong about duplicates. I create every entity and of course ZSet couldn't have duplicates because of ID. My temporary solution is using ZSet and make rangeWithScore where score is timestamp.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ZSetOperations.html is it possible to use with `@Resource(name="RedisTemplate")
private ZSetOperations<String, String> zSetOps;` and find `rangeByScoreWithScores`